# Convert using JAVA 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've tried to change this code to Java 8 streams. My code looks like this:

```
for(D d : n.getD()) {
    for(M m : d.getT().getM()) {
        if(m.getAC().contains(this)) {
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to convert it to java 8 streams. I've started like this:

```
  n.getD().stream()
        .map(m -> m.getT().getM())
```

but then I don't know if I should *map* again, or use a *filter*.

Comment: Because you have a list of lists, you might need flat map (see e.g. http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example ) , and then filter

Comment: @zm0 It's not possible, as what is returned is `d`, and not `m`.

Answer (score 4):

Other possible way is to use `anyMatch` instead of second `filter`

```
return n.getD().stream().filter(
   d -> d.getT().getM().stream().anyMatch(
         m -> m.getAC().contains(this)
   )
).findFirst(); // result will be Optional<D>
```

Answer (score 2):

one way to handle this:

```
return n.getD().stream().filter(d -> d.getT().getM().stream().filter(m -> m.getAC().contains(this)).findFirst().isPresent()).findFirst();
```

in this case a null value is possible.

Comment: Can you call `isPresent` on `filter()` result? `filter() returns Stream<T>` not an `Optional`.  So it should be `anyMatch(m -> m.getAC().contains(this))` instead of `filter(...).isPresent()`

Comment: Really. `anyMatch(predicate)` is preferable over `filter(predicate).findFirst().isPresent()`. And if you use find, use `findAny(…)` whenever it isn’t important to find the *first* one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your domain, but to keep it readable I would probably delegate and simplify to something like this:

```
return n.getD().stream()
               .filter(d -> d.getT().containsAC(this))
               .findFirst()
               .orElse(null);
```

And then in class T add the delegation method:

```
public boolean containsAC(AC ac) {
    return m.stream().anyMatch(m -> m.getAC().contains(ac));
}
```